# Add hours in countdown timer

Tags: jquery, timer, countdowntimer

my code:

`var mins = 30;`
`var secs = mins * 60;`
`var currentSeconds = 0;`
`var currentMinutes = 0;`
`setTimeout("Decrement("+secs+")",1000);`
`function Decrement(secs){`
`secs = parseInt(secs);`
`currentMinutes = Math.floor(secs / 60);`
`currentSeconds = secs % 60;`
`if(currentSeconds <= 9) currentSeconds = "0" + currentSeconds;`
`secs--;`
`$("#countdown").html(currentMinutes + ":" + currentSeconds);`
`if(secs !== -1){`
`setTimeout("Decrement("+secs+")",1000);`
`}`
`if(secs == 0){`
`alert('');`
`}`
`}`

its showing mins & secs, i want to add hours in it. how to do this.

Help appreciated. Thanx

Comment: You can get only help from here.Not your code.you have atleast start writing and show us.

Comment: just google for such a script, try to implement it, and if its not working, google again, and when its still not working, then come and ask. Or you can pay me, I can write such a script for you :)

Comment: @Jay please add the code to your question, write what you have tried and what is not working

Comment: @Baadshah above is my code, do you have any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one Countdown Timer for you

http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html

It has hours minutes and seconds.
You can set a date to where to do the countdown to and isn't hard to use if you read the documentation. simple usage: but when you want more settings i suggest to read the whole documentation

```
$(selector).countdown()
```